# how to make a service for locking applications in android?

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android application to lock applications.

I have selected the applications I want to lock and saved them in `SharedPreferences`, but I don't know how to make the service which will detect every application which will be launched on the mobile and compare that package name with the package names saved in `SharedPreferences` and display my lock activity instead of that application.

This is the code I have written in my service.

```
public class DetectorService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        String foregroundTaskPackageName;
        RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
            foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
            PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              return;
          }
        String[] abc = AppLockerPreference.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getApplicationList();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < abc.length ; i++)
        {
            if(abc[i].equals(foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName().toString()))
            {
                Intent lockIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryImages.class);
                lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(lockIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is my code where I select the applications and save them in `SharedPreferences`. I am starting the service `onPause` method of this code.

```
public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    AppLockerPreference ap;
    String prefApps[];
    boolean[] appflag;
    int[] arr;
    int count = 0;
    ImageView ivlock;
    Button bloc;
    ListView mylist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ap = new AppLockerPreference(getApplicationContext());
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
        mylist = getListView();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        startService(new Intent(this, DetectorService.class));
        //Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, sc.getString("app_loc", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ivlock = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_lockimg);
        if (ivlock.getDrawable() != null) {
            ivlock.setImageDrawable(null);
            appflag[position] = false;

        } else {
            ivlock.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_secure);
            appflag[position] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < appflag.length; ++i) {
            if (appflag[i] == true) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        arr = new int[count];
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < appflag.length; ++i) {
            if (appflag[i] == true) {
                arr[a] = i;
                a++;
            }
        }
        String[] prefapps = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            ApplicationInfo data = applist.get(arr[i]);
            prefapps[i] = data.packageName.toString();
        }
        ap.saveCount(count);
        ap.saveApplicationList(prefapps);
        ap.saveServiceEnabled(true);
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this, R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
            appflag = new boolean[listadaptor.getCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < listadaptor.getCount(); i++) {
                appflag[i] = false;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null, "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
        private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
        private Context context;
        private PackageManager packageManager;

        public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
            this.context = context;
            this.appsList = appsList;
            packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
            return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (null == view) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
            }

            ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
                TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
                ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
                ImageView lockimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_lockimg);
                String[] prefapps;
                prefapps = ap.getApplicationList();
                    //prefapps = new String[counter];
                boolean flag = false;
                String label = (String) data.packageName;
                for(int i=0;i<prefapps.length;++i)
                {
                    if(prefapps[i].equals(label))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        //Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, ddd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if(flag==true)
                {
                    lockimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_secure);
                    appflag[position]=true;
                    appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
                    iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
                }
                else
                {
                    lockimg.setImageDrawable(null);
                    appflag[position] = false;
                    appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
                    iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
                }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my own and found a way to make the service. Here is the code.

```
public class DetectorService extends Service {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final boolean running = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(running){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

            String[] prefs;
            AppLockerPreference ap = new AppLockerPreference(getApplicationContext());
            prefs = ap.getApplicationList();
            for(int i = 0; i < prefs.length ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j< RunningTask.size() ; j++)
                {
                    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(j);
                    String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getPackageName();
                    if(prefs[i].equals(activityOnTop))
                    {
                        Intent lockIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryImages.class);
                        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(lockIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
    ).start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}